# multiple image upload using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, codeigniter-2

im having a page that will insert username, ID and the user must be able to upload upto 10 images .

The main problem that im having is when it comes to uploading multiple images using codeigniter.

1. can someone suggest me how can i pass each image path of each
   individual image to the array so i can pass it to the database.
2. and if the user selects to upload less than 10 images, like 2 or 5
   then how can i ignore the error that says a file hasn't been
   selected and jst pass only the images that has been uploaded.

   ```
   <form method="post" action="uploader/go" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input name="username" type="text" /><br />
   <input name="nid" type="text" /><br />
   <input type="file" name="image1" /><br />
   <input type="file" name="image2" /><br />
   <input type="file" name="image3" /><br />
   <input type="file" name="image4" /><br />
   <input type="file" name="image5" /><br />
   <input type="file" name="image6" /><br />
   <input type="file" name="image7" /><br />
   <input type="file" name="image8" /><br />
   <input type="file" name="image9" /><br />
   <input type="file" name="image10" /><br />
   <input type="submit" name="go" value="Upload!!!" />
   </form>
   ```

sample controller

```
$image_data=array('image_info' => $this->upload->data('image')); 
$image_path=$image_data['image_info']['full_path'];

$data =array(
            'id'=>uniqid('id_'),
                    'nID'=>$this->input->post('nid'),
            'username'=>$username,
            'image1'=>$image_path
}
```

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change the input names to:

```
<input type="file" name="image[1]" /><br />
<input type="file" name="image[2]" /><br />
<input type="file" name="image[3]" /><br />
```

instead and `$this->upload->data('image')` will be an array.

And then you can do:

```
foreach($this->upload->data('image') as $image) {
   passItToTheDatabase(); // your custom function

}
```

Comment: cool... thanks but what if an image hasnt been selected? how do i skip that error?

Comment: You can set even `<input type="file" name="image[]" /><br />` for evey file fields so IDs would be generated automatically by php